# Keeping changes across branches

Tags: git, github

I am pretty new to Git and think I have managed to get myself a bit lost.

So I get a Jira task, and from that I create a branch like so

```
git branch J12345-123
git checkout J12345-123
```

I then work on the branch, and when ready commit and push

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some message"
git push
```

Sometimes the push ask me to set upstream, not too sure what this is? e.g.

```
git push --set-upstream origin J12345-123
```

Anyways, once everything is done on this branch, I merge it with the master branch.

The issue I am facing is this.  I created a new branch and was working on it (lets call it Branch A).  I then had the need to create and work on another branch (Branch B) before I had finished my work on Branch A.  As such, I committed and pushed my changes for Branch A.  I did not merge with master as I am not finished on this branch.

From Branch A, I then created Branch B and this included the modifications I had made in Branch A (which is what I wanted).  I then worked on Branch B, committed and pushed it.  I then merged Branch B with master.

Now, I go back to Branch A, and none of the work I done on Branch B is there.  I want what I did on Branch B to now be present on Branch A.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply merge B to A:

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

Since you have created B from A, the merge will be a trivial fast-forward one.
Assuming you did not make any commit on A since you switch to B.

```
a--a        (A)
    \
     b--b   (B)
         \
          M (master)
```

Merging B to A means A HEAD will move to B

```
a--a        
    \
     b--b   (A, B)
         \
          M (master)
```